# get validations from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

How cat I get list of validations defined in model

Example:

```
class ModelName
  validates_presence_of :field_name
  validates_inclusion_of :sex, :in => %w(M F)
end
```

I need Hash like:

```
{:field_name => 'required', :sex => 'Must be in: M, F'}
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for basic needs.

You can do this to get a hash of all validators.

```
ModelName.validators
```

If you want to get the validators for a specific field :

```
ModelName.validators_on(:attribute)
```

Comment: Cool! It's better, than plugin

Comment: Just a note, this is only available in Rails 3.  For earlier rails apps, the plugin is the way to go.

Comment: How can I get this if I am using a custom validate method like
    `validate :check_name_blank`
Inside this method I am checking name is present and some other stuffs. So while I am doing `ModelName.validators_on :name`, I am getting an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

This code yields an array of required fields. It should be adaptable to your needs.

```
@required_fields = []
ModelName.validators.each do |v|
  @required_fields << v.attributes.first if v.kind == :presence
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add validations dynamically in your models, you can use the instance to list the validations:

```
product = Product.new
product.singleton_class.validators_on(:price)
#=> [#<ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidaton>]
```

Tested in Rails 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no native way to do it, but a quick Google (for "rails reflect validations") turns up [this plugin](http://github.com/redinger/validation_reflection).

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me:

`ModelName.validators_on(:sex).first.options[:in]`

*answer:* **["M","F"]**

You want something like this:

```
field = :sex
sexs = ModelName.validators_on(field).first.options[:in]
hsh = {}
hsh[:field_name] = (ModelName.validators.grep(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator).flat_map(&:attributes).include?(field)) ? 'required': 'optional'
hsh[field] ="Must be in: #{sexs.to_sentence(two_words_connector: ', ')}"
```

*answer hsh:* **{:field_name=>"required", :sex=>"Must be in: M, F"}**

I use **Rails 6.1.4.1**